# Block Call on Sony Ericsson Phones

Tags: android

im trying to write an app to block calls for the phone. Current using the following code to block calls.

```
Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK);
event = KeyEvent.changeFlags(event, KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS);
buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, event);
context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown, Manifest.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED);
```

It works on Galaxy Nexus, Galaxy SII, and HTC Sensational. But it does not work on SE Xperia S, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

it seems as if you are making use of functionality that makes this possible in the google phone application. However as far as I can understand there exists no official support in android framework. Sony has chosen to change their dialler due to slightly different and updated requirements - and it seems as if the described behavior was then lost in the process.
Kind regards
  /Johan